# iOS reordering a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I have a UITableView that reads data from a sql db.

When i reorder the data it only changes the top and bottom ones

[image]

Dragging 1 from top to bottom

[image]

When i let it go at 5 it only switches the top and bottom ones.

[image]
I am using the following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

            [myStringsArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];

}
```

How can i reorder the list? So it'll be 2,3,4,5,1 and not 5,2,3,4,1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exchange is not a proper way to do it you should use this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
     id buffer = [myStringsArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
     [myStringsArray removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];  
     [myStringsArray insertObject:buffer atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Edited to match comment below.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer but it was rejected because the edit was too short! Here is the edit. The last line above should be:     
    [myStringsArray insertObject:buffer atIndex:toIndexPath.row];